# Azure Container Apps quota

Tags: azure-container-apps

As per Container apps documentation it says an environment can have maximum of 20 cores. Does it mean that microservices inside one environment cannot request beyond 20 cores when it is required to scale-out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Bjz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Total core usage in an environment cannot exceed the default 20 cores for all scenarios including scale-out. You can request increase for the limit via support.